# Why am I getting "Invalid object name 'sys.sysobjvalues'."

Tags: sql-server, system-tables, catalogs, dac, sys

When I run

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('sys.assembly_files'));
```

I can see that there is a self-join on `sys.sysobjvalues`, but when I try to select that table I get,

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.sysobjvalues'.
```

What's going on here? Why is that object name invalid?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the tables that can only be accessed over DAC, [from this blog](http://jongurgul.com/blog/sql-object-decryption/comment-page-7/)

> They had been moved to the imageval column of sys.sysobjvalues, which can only be accessed when using the Dedicated Admin Connection (DAC).

Prolly not a good idea, but for proof it'll work connect to DAC (`-S admin:localhost` on Linux)

```
sqlcmd -S admin:localhost -U sa -q "SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjvalues;" | less -S
```